# Update Flash in FireFox in Linux Mint?

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, flash

I am trying to update Flash, but I still get a massage telling me to update it.

I'm using Firefox 37.0.2 and Flash 11.2.202.425 on Linux Mint.

I followed [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Upgrade-Adobe-Flash-Player-on-Linux-Mint) tutorial, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Are you trying to update [Shockwave](http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/otherversions/) or [Flash](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/)? They are different plugins. Shockwave isn't even available for Linux.

Comment: (1) What version of Mint are you using? (2) Are you updating Flash from the command line or from other ways? How? (3) What error message do you see? (4) What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep flash`?

Comment: The message is: Shockwave Flash está considerado vulnerable y debe ser actualizado. The version of Mint does not matter.The howto is in the link.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy: Why did you delete the Bugzilla link while still leaving the actual URL in the question's source?

Comment: @Karan `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

to assume LM17/17.1  you need

Opt 1) the fleshplayer repo from webup8te enabled (which is pepperflash form chrome modified both ubuntu (the codebase for linux mint) & for firefox

Opt 2) install pepperflash from the native repos with:

> sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
>
> sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install

Both of the the pepperflash commands in both options can be achieved via the gui as well if command line is not your thing: ( shown below)

Opt 1 ) (via gui) Open Software Sources form menu and add this repository

> ppa:skunk/pepper-flash

then install it via  Synaptic (your package manager (use the search bar with term 'pepperflash'

Opt 2) (via --gui)  Open Synaptic  and search flash  then install

> pepperflashplugin-nonfree

Comment: I did that. In the links are the howto for Chrome and Firefox. I does not work!

Comment: apt policy *flash*  gives what ?

Comment: `flashplayer-mozilla:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  3:11.2.202.327-dmo3
  Tabla de versión:
     3:11.2.202.327-dmo3 0
        500 http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia/ testing/non-free amd64 Packages`

Comment: try this: " sudo apt install flashplayer-mozilla " then

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: That's installed by default on mint.  As of now though, it's not up to date.